# How to make my Smart Home action available on my device?

Tags: actions-on-google

How to test my Smart Home actions?

Some time ago I did the codelab "Smart Home Washer". Created action became available in the "Manage accounts" list in my Home app, with prefix '[test]'. Sure, I created action by the same account as I use on my phone.

Today I've done the same lab, but a new task isn't available in this list. When I disconnected old account, it also disappeared from list.

Something changed during last time? How to make my task available on my devices?

Comment: This is tagged Firebase but it's unclear what the connection is between your Smart Home Washer and Firebase it. If it's not related to Firebase, the tag should be removed.

Comment: You should make sure you have begun testing your Action and that you're logged into the right account on your phone.